# Force theme refresh with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, theme

Is there a way to force the theme to refresh using PowerShell?

When I deploy a CSS file with my style, I currently have to change theme, then back again manually.

I would like to know if it is possible to force a refresh using PowerShell.

I don't want to do an IIS reset, I want minimal farm interruption.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure this isnt just a client side cache problem?

Changing the CSS files in a theme will require a CTRL+F5 in your browser if it already has loaded the theme CSS files in its cache.

Comment: SharePoint caches the themed CSS files too. The theme engine caches them when the theme is changed.

Comment: Here is a reference, but I experienced it myself too: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/vi-VN/sharepoint2010customization/thread/2b64ca5e-eb21-48fd-aff6-b1f387a8b0a6